# I have multiple lines of text that print in typewriter animation. However, when I refresh my browser the different lines of texts get mixed up

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple lines of text that print in typewriter animation, but when I refresh my browser the different lines of texts get mixed up.

Something like this "****eI icsr eAahtmeedr .t hWiesl cWoembes ittoe muys iWnegb sHiTtMeL,. CSS, and JS.**"

Click around Run snippet 5 or 6 times and including the code buttons, and you will see it see the problem.

The intro is a automatic animation when you first land the page which reads "Hello! My name is Frank. Welcome to my Website."

Tell Me More button prints out "I created this Website using HTML, CSS, and JS."

Nice! button prints out "This website is to showcase my skills."

Ok prints out "You should hire me. Scroll down to see why."

*This is just a template. I am actually very new to Java and getting familiar with CSS and HTML. I am creating a portfolio and also learning to code, so bear with me.*

I am basically trying to copy this website here https://www.amysboyd.com

I would like the buttons to disappear like in the website, but I don't know how to do that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Portfolio Styles.css" </head>

  <body>

    <div class="abouttextsection">
      <h1 id='output'></h1>
      <script>
        var a = 0;
        var introtxt = 'Hello! My name is Frank. Welcome to my Website.';
        var speed = 50;

        function aboutintro() {
          if (a < introtxt.length) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += introtxt.charAt(a);
            a++;
            setTimeout(aboutintro, 50);
          }
        }
        window.onload = aboutintro;



        var doc, bod, I, TypeMaker; // for use on other loads
        addEventListener('load', function() {
          doc = document;
          bod = doc.body;
          I = function(id) {
            return doc.getElementById(id);
          }
          TypeMaker = function(element, interval) {
            this.element = element;
            this.interval = interval || 50;
            var t = this,
              r;
            this.type = function(string) {
              if (r) clearInterval(r);
              var s = string.split(''),
                l = s.length,
                i = 0;
              var p = 'value' in this.element ? 'value' : 'innerHTML';
              this.element[p] = '';
              r = setInterval(function() {
                t.element[p] += s[i++];
                if (i === l) {
                  clearInterval(r);
                  r = undefined;
                }
              }, t.interval);
            }
          }
          var typer = new TypeMaker(I('output')),
            First_test = I('First_test'),
            Second_test = I('Second_test'),
            Third_test = I('Third_test');
          var testArray = [''];
          var testArrayL = testArray.length;
          First_test.onclick = function() {
            typer.type('I created this Website using HTML, CSS, and JS.');
          }
          Second_test.onclick = function() {
            typer.type('This website is to showcase my skills.');
          }
          Third_test.onclick = function() {
            typer.type('You should hire me. Scroll down to see why.');
          }

        });
      </script>

      <div class="aboutsectionbutton">
        <button id='First_test' type='button' value='Tell Me More' />Tell Me More</button>
        <button id='Second_test' type='button' value='Nice!' />Nice!</button>
        <button id='Third_test'>Ok</button>


      </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java?

Comment: @kiner_shah My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Add fadeOut transition to css class ->

**CSS:**

```
 .hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s .25s, opacity .25s linear;
}
```

And on click event just add this class ->

**JS:**

```
 Second_test.onclick = function() {
          this.classList.add('hidden')
            typer.type('This website is to showcase my skills.');
          }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/9hd3zgkv/5/)